# Spectrum and continuous spectrum of operator $T:C[0,1]→C[0,1]$, where $Tx(t)=tx(t)$.

Tags: functional-analysis

I proved that the Spectrum is $[0,1]$ and the Point Spectrum is $\emptyset$, now I need to prove that $\overline{range(\lambda I -T)}=C[0,1]$, this to find the Continuous Spectrum, but is not easy to me because the metric in C[0,1] is confusing. Could anyone explain me?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $\lambda \in [0,1]$, every function $x$ in the range of $\lambda I - T$ satisfies $x(\lambda) = 0$.  Show that the set $E_\lambda$ of all $x$ satisfying $x(\lambda) = 0$ is closed.

This is trivial when you think about it.  Suppose $x_n$ is a sequence of elements of $E_\lambda$ which converge to $x$ in norm.  That is to say, $x_n$ is a sequence of continuous functions on $[0,1]$, all satisfying $x_n(\lambda) = 0$ which converge uniformly to $x$.  Then it is clear that $x(\lambda) = 0$ too, so $x \in E_\lambda$.

Since the range of $\lambda I - T$ is contained in a proper closed subset of $C([0,1])$, its closure is not $C([0,1])$.

Comment: Thanks, it was a mistake for my part.